# SFML C++: mysterious bugs happening in my software possibly relating to <iostream> and header files?

Tags: c++, header-files, sfml

I am making a project and to keep it organized I made a header file called include.h that will store all the global variables and includes.
yesterday it worked but today it puts me some weird bugs and I can't find the answer to them.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

enum GameModes { AgainstComputer, AgainstPlayer, AgainstPc, GameModeScreen }; <- error: C2011: enum 
                                                                                 type redefinition
/*
    enum explanation:
        0 = play against AI
        1 = play online against player
        2 = play locally against a friend
        3 = open the screen showing game modes
*/

// font name
std::string fontName = "Arvo-BoldItalic.ttf"; <- error: C2374: redefinition; multiple initialization
```

this is the code for the includes header, and it has 2 errors that say I initialized the variables twice, even though I didn't.

other bugs relating are in the normal functions:

```
GameModes welcomeWindow(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Event event)
{
    sf::Font font;

    if (!font.loadFromFile("C:\\chess\\Fonts\\" + fontName)) <- error: C2088: illegal for class 
                                                                (where is there a class involved?)
    {
        std::cout << "Error loading font " << fontName << std::endl; <- error: C2088: illegal for 
                                                                        class (where is there a class 
                                                                        involved?)
        exit(1);
    }
```

I am basically trying to load a font from a file named after the file name in the includes.h header but it makes two errors:(stated in the lines of the code)

Comment: If you have build errors, please copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question, separately so they are easy to read. And add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: As a possible hint, do you include the same header file multiple times in the same [translation unit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))? Do you have proper [include guards](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)?

Comment: In addition to the missing include guard, you also need to replace `std::string fontName` either with `const std::string fontName` or `inline std::string fontName`.

Comment: You should have extracted a [mcve], it might have given you the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the redefinitions are happening due to lack of header guards!

Maybe today you are including that header in two files, so now that code gets ran twice and thus all it's symbols redefined.

You can also use `#pragma once` at the beginning of all your header files to tell your linker to only include that file once.

Hmmm, I don't have much experience with globals declared in headers, but I think I once had a weird bug like that and I had to forward declare the global variable at the top in all the cpp files it is used in with

```
extern fontName;
```

Wiki post about header guards:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

To add onto my answer. All lines that start with `#`, are actually preprocessor directives, which means their changes happen before your code is even compiled.

You can imagine that when your code has an include, all that header actually gets pasted into that file with the include!

Also, what `#ifndef NAME` means, is that ONLY when the symbol `NAME` is NOT known to the precompiler the body of that control structure will run.

If it is, then all that is between that #ifndef and `#endif` will be ignored.

Notice how the first thing we do is `#define NAME`, thus making it known to the preprocessor that the symbol exists, but for this end we don't even need to define the value of `NAME`, as it is not relevant.

This way, the next time the preprocessor finds the `#include "thatFile.h"`, it won't actually copy any code.

There are more control structures of this sort. For example, one could use `#ifdef __unix__` to include headers that only exist in Linux, thus not causing errors when compiling in different OS and allowing for greater portability!

Edit: changed the link to desktop and English
edit2: my explanation was wrong